# How can I show that supremum of the product is $\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, upper-lower-bounds

If $Z$ is a centered normal random variable with variance $\sigma^2$ (hence sub-gaussian also), how can I show that

$$
\sup\limits_{t>0} \Bigg( P(Z \geq t)\exp{\Big(\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}}\Big) \Bigg) = \frac{1}{2}
$$
I tried using the fact that $P(Z \geq t) = \int\limits_{t}^{\infty} f(z)dz$, but it did not help to find a closed form.

Comment: Have you tried a few numerical examples, to give you  a hint about what values of $t$ come close to maximizing the quantity in question, or to suggest ranges of $t$ that do not come close to maximizing the quantity? Does the quantity in question depend continuously on $t$, and if so, can you narrow down your search for the supremum somehow?

Comment: @kimchilover, since exp is a convex function, supremum can be infinity.  But since the probability goes to zero for large values of t, it is ruled out. Fom my numerical experiments, it seems t should be between (0,1). I also tried with the inequality $P(Z \geq t) \leq exp(-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2})$.  Which tells me that supremum should be less than 1.

Comment: So the supremum is attained at an endpoint ($t=0$) or at  a calculus maximum, or in the limit, as $t\to\infty$?

Comment: $t=0$ gives me the result $\frac{1}{2}$. But it is experimental, but analytically how can I show ?

Comment: @PaulSinclair, what about the term $P(Z \geq t) = \int\limits_{t}^{\infty} f(z)dz$.  The integral applies only to the first term right ?.  How can I take derivative in this case ?

Comment: That part is not a problem. Just use the product rule. However, I foolishly forgot that the derivative of $\int_t^\infty f(z)dz$ is $-f(t)$ because we are differentiating with respect to the lower limit. Which breaks my claim that the derivative is positive, so I deleted it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair. So is this is general correct ?  $ \frac{d}{dx}  (\int f(x)dx g(x) = \int \frac{d}{dx}[ f(x)g(x)] dx$

Comment: No. Not at all. The product rule is $$\frac{d}{dt}\left(h(t)g(t)\right) = \frac {dh}{dt}(t)g(t) + h(t)\frac{dg}{dt}(t)$$For your problem, $h(t) = \int_t^\infty f(z)dz$ so $\frac {dh}{dt}(t) = -f(t)$, while $g(t) = e^{t^2/2\sigma^2}$, so $\frac {dg}{dt}(t) =\frac t{\sigma^2}e^{t^2/2\sigma^2}$. So the overall derivative is $$-f(t)e^{t^2/2\sigma^2} + \left(\int_t^\infty f(z)dz\right) \frac t{\sigma^2}e^{t^2/2\sigma^2}$$My mistake had the first term without the negative sign. That would have left everything positive for $t > 0$ (since $f$ is a probability density).

Answer (score 0):

Hint.  The conditional expectation $E[Z|Z\ge t]$ is obviously $\ge t$ and is easily calculable by calculus.

In particular, let $\sigma=$ without loss of generality, and write $P(Z\in A)=\int_A \varphi(x)\,dx $ where $\varphi(x)=\exp(-x^2/2)/\sqrt{2\pi}$. Let $h(t)=P(Z\ge t)\exp(t^2/2)$ so $$h'(t)=-\varphi(t)\exp(t^2/2)+P(Z\ge t)t\exp(t^2/2).$$
Since $h(0)=1/2$, it suffices to show $h'(t)\le 0$ for $t\le0$, that is,
$$P(Z\ge t)t\exp(t^2/2)\le \varphi(t)\exp(t^2/2),$$ that is
$$t\le\frac{\varphi(t)}{P(Z\ge t)}\tag{*}.$$
But $$E[Z|Z\ge t]P(Z\ge t) = \int_t^\infty x \varphi(x)\,dx = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_t^\infty x e^{-x^2/2}\,dx = \varphi(x),$$
so (*) becomes $t\le E[Z|Z\ge t],$ which  clearly holds.

Comment: But here since we do not have summation, we can not write in terms of expectation right ?.  What I infer is, you are referring to the fact that $\int P(Z\geq t) = E(Z)$, but it holds on for +ve Z, and we do not have integral over probability. Can you please elaborate a bit ?

Comment: I elaborated, even though I don't understand your comment in detail.